# Divide Matching Rows in Table by Matching Rows in Other Table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My BigQuery database models an online game. It has tables for:

- `raid`, an instance of the game that occurs in a `channel`. Example:

  ```
  +--------------------------------------+---------------+
  |                  id                  |    channel    |
  +--------------------------------------+---------------+
  | 4dc0fd49-3d13-4271-b5fb-2fc8a3bfa0c6 | #antonidas    |
  | d400e1cd-10af-4cb4-8a24-1a3f7ed994c0 | #anvilmar     |
  | 532c95b6-9398-4ae4-bd97-d9a0aed3b9cc | #antonidas    |
  | b7779b4e-5042-45ab-a356-5f2e08b51f1f | #antonidas    |
  | 41160b3b-bcd5-4f00-b3c4-972054e64cab | #antonidas    |
  +--------------------------------------+---------------+
  ```
- `entry`, the people that entered the raid. Example:

  ```
  +--------------------------------------+-----------+
  |               raid_id                |  raider   |
  +--------------------------------------+-----------+
  | 41160b3b-bcd5-4f00-b3c4-972054e64cab | Blackrock |
  | 41160b3b-bcd5-4f00-b3c4-972054e64cab | Coilfang  |
  | 4dc0fd49-3d13-4271-b5fb-2fc8a3bfa0c6 | Blackrock |
  | d400e1cd-10af-4cb4-8a24-1a3f7ed994c0 | Blackrock |
  | b7779b4e-5042-45ab-a356-5f2e08b51f1f | Blackrock |
  | b7779b4e-5042-45ab-a356-5f2e08b51f1f | Gilneas   |
  | 532c95b6-9398-4ae4-bd97-d9a0aed3b9cc | Blackrock |
  +--------------------------------------+-----------+
  ```
- `win`, the people that won the raid. Example:

  ```
  +--------------------------------------+-----------+
  |               raid_id                |  raider   |
  +--------------------------------------+-----------+
  | d400e1cd-10af-4cb4-8a24-1a3f7ed994c0 | Blackrock |
  | 4dc0fd49-3d13-4271-b5fb-2fc8a3bfa0c6 | Blackrock |
  | 41160b3b-bcd5-4f00-b3c4-972054e64cab | Coilfang  |
  +--------------------------------------+-----------+
  ```

I'm trying to determine **the overall win rate for raids that occurred in a specific channel**. The win rate is the total number of `win` rows divided by the total number of `entry` rows if the raid for the win/entry raid is channel C. Something like:

[image: Formula]

The closest I've come is by running 2 sub-select queries, but I feel there must be a better way, where I don't have to repeat myself and run essentially 3 queries total.

```sql
SELECT
  (
  SELECT
    COUNT(*)
  FROM
    win
  JOIN
    raid
  ON
    win.raid_id = raid.id
  WHERE
    raid.channel = "#antonidas") / (
  SELECT
    COUNT(*)
  FROM
    entry
  JOIN
    raid
  ON
    entry.raid_id = raid.id
  WHERE
    raid.channel = "#antonidas") AS `win_rate`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should give you your desired results. It `LEFT JOIN`s `raid` to `entry` and `win` and then counts the number of distinct rows in each of those tables to determine the number of entries and wins per channel:

```
SELECT r.channel,
       COUNT(DISTINCT r.id) AS raids,
       COUNT(DISTINCT w.raid_id) AS wins, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT e.raid_id) AS entries,
       CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT w.raid_id) AS FLOAT) / COUNT(DISTINCT e.raid_id) AS win_rate
FROM raid r
LEFT JOIN entry e ON e.raid_id = r.id
LEFT JOIN win w ON w.raid_id = r.id
GROUP BY r.channel
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
channel     raids   wins    entries     win_rate
#antonidas  4       2       4           0.5
#anvilmar   1       1       1           1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w62hcuuWpCeLBThom5tbt1/0)

Note you can add `WHERE channel = ...` before the `GROUP BY` to restrict results to one particular channel. Also you can remove any columns you don't actually need, I put them all in to demonstrate the numbers being computed from your sample data.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you. I will try this out in a moment. Followup question: How did you build the output in your answer? Did you literally transcribe my sample data to your own tables? When I was writing my question, I was wondering about the best way for answerers to "see" the data, but still hopefully be able to import it into their own tables for testing. Is there an table formatting standard for SO I should be following?

Comment: I was able to replicate your output by getting rid of the `CAST() AS FLOAT`. BigQuery doesn't seem to understand it, but apparently doesn't need it in this case. Do you think by removing that, I've retained the semantics of your query? @Nick

Comment: @t-mart the `CAST` was necessary on the demo site (I had to use PostgreSQL as it didn't support bigquery); otherwise it treated it as an integer division (resulting in 0 instead of 0.5). In terms of creating the demo, if you look in the bottom left of the schema SQL frame, there's a "text to DDL" button; I copied and pasted your data into the window that opens. It can be really helpful for questions such as this if the come with a fiddle already prepared.